# Code ignoring user input and randomly spitting out chopped off strings printed later

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to call a function that will randomly generate a string from a table.
(ignore the strange purpose, I was looking for a challenge and my friend suggested this)
When the function is called, it ignores all 'cin' and spits out this response.
Toaster Bathinal death total is:
C:\Users\MH\source\repos\suicidefun\x64\Debug\suicidefun.exe (process 25852) exited with code 0.

My code is this:

```
// imports
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//var
string methods[21] = { "Hanging", "Shooting", "Poisoning", "Drinking Bleach", "Toaster Bath", "something idk", "Eating something you are allergic to", "Fall damage", "Mr. Hands", "Stabbing", "Shoving a pointy object in you", "Thinking you are in a dream and doing something stupid","Drunk driving","Overdose","Drowning","Fire","Starving or dehydrating","Driving off a cliff","Driving into a family of five's ford fiesta","Eat glass","Suicide by cop" };
time_t current_time = time(NULL);
int random;
bool again = true;
int killcount = 0;
string x = "N/A";
int check = 0;
bool valid = false;
char ans = 'n';


void thing(){   
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    int random = rand() % 20;
    cout << methods[random];
    killcount++;
    while (valid = false) {
        cout << "Kill yourself again? (y/n)";
        cin >> x;
        if (x != "y" || "n" || "Y" || "N") {
            cout << "invalid answer";
        }
        else {
            valid = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (x == "y") {
        cout << "Current death total is:" + killcount;
    }
    else if (x == "Y") {
        cout << "Current death total is:" + killcount;
    }
    else {
        again = false;
        cout << "Final death total is:" + killcount;
    }
}

int main() {
    thing();
    return 0;
}
```

What I was expecting to happen is for a random string to be output, the variable killcount to increase by 1, the program to ask the user if they wanted to continue or stop, the program to then output the value of killcount and if the user chose to stop, set the value of the boolean again to false.

Comment: `while (valid = false)` will never run. I guess you meant `while (valid == false)`?

Comment: `cout << "doh" + 1;` will print out `oh`.

Comment: And whomever taught you to use lots of global variable, please don't listen to that person again, or read that book, or follow that tutorial. It's a bad habit, especially for variables that should be local.

Comment: BTW, `x != "y" || "n" ....` will not be have the way you expect (look up operator precedence).  Recode as `x != "y" && x != "n"``...

Comment: Research the internet for how to *transform* a string to all upper case or all lower case.  If you transform before you compare, you will need fewer compares.

Comment: Note: It is almost always better to have the call to `srand` up near the top of `main` rather than in a function where it can be called multiple times and cause `rand` to produce unexpectedly similar results over and over.

Comment: You'll need `#include <string>` and `using std::string;`

Comment: To concatenate for `cout`, use `<<` not `+`.

Comment: You should get more comfortable with using logical operators like `||` correctly as you use them incorrectly in one place, and then when there's a good opportunity for using them, ignore them entirely and instead duplicate the code. Remember each `==` or `!=` is evaluated against *one and only one thing*, `a == b || c` evaluates `b || c` first, then compares `a` to that.

Comment: "_ignore the strange purpose_" - it is hard to ignore the rather distasteful subject of this code.  Suicide and self harm is not at all funny.

Comment: Forget about puzzles for now and focus on learning the language. There are a lot of mistakes in the code covered in the early chapters of a [good language text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/4581301).

Comment: It appears that there are a few issues in your code. For instance, the correct condition should be written as follows:
 if (!(x == "y" || x =="n" || x =="Y" || x =="N"))
And you should be converting killcount to a string before adding it to the constant string. The way you wrote it, the code simply shifts start position of the pointer of the constant string. 
It's important to note that this forum is not intended for debugging assistance. Please be mindful of this and try to address debugging concerns appropriately."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some of the problems I found with your program.

###### Avoid `using namespace std;`

Professional programmers do not, in general, use `using namespace std;`. Neither should you. Instead, just type out `std::` as a prefix for any name you need to use from the C++ Standard Library. For example, `std::cout`.

`using namespace std` is a [*using directive*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/using). @Chris points out in the comments below that *using declarations*, such as `using std::swap` and `using std::cout`, are a different story (provided they are used judiciously). See below. In those cases, it may be okay to use `swap` or `cout` without a prefix.

###### Global variables

In a large program, using "global" variables is problematic, because it is hard to keep track of where they are getting changed. Proving program correctness (for all execution paths) becomes almost impossible. Even worse, when you have a bug, because one of your global variables gets the wrong value, it can be very difficult to track down where it went bad.

In the example program below, I have made your variables "local".

###### Assignment vs. equality

In C++, *assignment* uses `=`, while testing for *equality* uses `==`.

```cpp
// This is wrong:
while (valid = false) ...

// This is correct:
while (valid == false) ...

// This is even better:
while (valid) ...
```

By itsef, `valid` will either be `true` or `false`. But so will the answer to the test `valid == true`, so best practice is just to use the variable by itself.

The assignment expression `valid = false` sets variable `valid` to `false`, *and then returns `false` to the surrounding expression.* Thus, `while (valid = false)` is the same as `while(false)`.

###### Repeated comparisons

With repeated comparisons, you have to restate the variable name for each comparison.

```cpp
// This is wrong:
if (x != "y" || "n" || "Y" || "N") ...

// This is correct:
if (x != "y" && x != "n" && x != "Y" && x != "N") ...
```

Note that you have to join the tests with `&&`. In pseudocode, that give you:

> If x is not "y" AND x is not "n" AND x is not "Y" AND x is not "N" ...

###### Cannot use `+` to join a string with a number

In C++, you cannot use `+` to concatenate a string literal with a number.

```cpp
// This is wrong:
cout << "Current death total is:" + killcount;

// This is correct:
cout << "Current death total is: " << killcount;

// So is this:
std::string s = "Current death total is: " + std::to_string(killcount);
```

The reason your program "spits out chopped off strings" is because expressions such as `"Current death total is:" + killcount` are valid *pointer expressions*. When `killcount` is 3, for instance, it returns a pointer to the 4th character in `"Current death total is:"`. When that pointer is output using `std::cout`, the result is `"rent death total is:"`.

###### Missing outer loop

Function `thing` is missing an outer loop that should be controlled by variable `again`.

```cpp
void thing(){   
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    bool again;
    do {
        // play game ...
    } while (again);
    std::cout << "Final death total is: " << killcount << "\n\n";
}
```

###### Random numbers

The algorithm used by function `rand` is *implementation dependent.* Each compiler defines its own version. Some compilers use a good algorithm, while others do not. Meanwhile, the Mersenne twister engine, `std::mt19937`, introduced in C++11, is required to be the same on all compilers.

Even if `rand` is okay on your compiler, `rand() % 20` is definitely not. The random numbers it generates are not uniformly distributed. Certain values are returned more often than others. (See the [pigeonhole_ principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).) That is why `std::uniform_int_distribution` was added to C++11. The numbers it returns are guaranteed to be uniformly distributed.

I usually wrap `std::mt19937` and `std::uniform_int_distribution` into a simple class such as class `RNG` below. That way, I can have a separate member function for each kind of random number I need. For your game, however, I only needed one such function: `random_method`.

```cpp
class RNG
{
    std::mt19937 mt{ std::random_device{}() };
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> dist;
    using param_type = std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t>::param_type;
public:
    auto random_method(std::size_t size) {
        return dist(mt, param_type{ 0, size - 1 });
    }
};
```

Here are a few notes about class `RNG`.

- In C++, `std::size_t` is the type used by subscripts to an array. That is why I instantiated `std::uniform_int_distribution` with `std::size_t`. I want it to return a random subscript.
- `std::random_device{}()` returns a random 32-bit seed that is used by the constructor of `std::mt19937` as its seed.
- `param_type{ 0, size - 1 }` constructs a `param` object that contains the minimum and maximum values that will be returned by the `std::uniform_int_distribution` object, `dist`.
- `dist` needs two arguments in order to generate a random number: First, the random number engine `mt`, and, second, a `param` object giving the range of numbers to use.

###### Call a function to get keyboard input

In general, I call a function every time I need to get input from `std::cin`. Here is a short function that gets a `Y/N` response from the user, while rejecting invalid responses.

It uses `std::getline`, so you have to be careful when you mix it with statements like `std::cin >> value;` , because `std::cin >> value;` leaves a hanging `'\n'` on the input stream. You have to get rid of it, usually by calling `std::cin.ignore`, before calling `get_yes_no`. That is not a problem here, however, because nothing like `std::cin >> value;` is used anywhere.

```cpp
bool get_yes_no(
    std::string const& prompt,
    std::istream& ist = std::cin,
    std::ostream& ost = std::cout)
{
    std::string s;
    for (;;)
    {
        if (!prompt.empty())
            ost << prompt;
        else 
            ost << "Yes or No? (y/n): ";
        if (!std::getline(ist, s))
            throw std::runtime_error(
                "ERROR: `std::getline` failed unexpectedly.");
        s = to_upper(trim_whitespace(s));
        if (s == "Y" || s == "YES")
            return true;
        if (s == "N" || s == "NO")
            return false;
        ost << "Invalid entry. Please reenter.\n\n";
    }
}
```

###### Helper functions

`get_yes_no` calls a pair of helper functions. The first converts a string to upper case.

```cpp
std::string to_upper(std::string s) noexcept
{
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(),
        [](unsigned char c) { return std::toupper(c); }
    );
    return s;
}
```

The second trims leading and trailing whitespace from a string.

```cpp
auto trim_whitespace(std::string const& s) -> std::string
{
    // Trim leading and trailing whitespace from string `s`.
    auto const first{ s.find_first_not_of(" \f\n\r\t\v")};
    if (first == std::string::npos)
        return {};
    auto const last{ s.find_last_not_of(" \f\n\r\t\v") };
    enum : std::string::size_type { one = 1u };
    return s.substr(first, (last - first + one));
}
```

###### Simplified game function

With these helper functions in tow, the code for your program simplifies to this.

```cpp
void kill_game()
{
    char const* methods[] = {
        "Hanging"
        , "Shooting"
        , "Poisoning"
        , "Drinking Bleach"
        , "Toaster Bath"
        , "something idk"
        , "Eating something you are allergic to"
        , "Fall damage"
        , "Mr. Hands"
        , "Stabbing"
        , "Shoving a pointy object in you"
        , "Thinking you are in a dream and doing something stupid"
        , "Drunk driving"
        , "Overdose"
        , "Drowning"
        , "Fire"
        , "Starving or dehydrating"
        , "Driving off a cliff"
        , "Driving into a family of five's ford fiesta"
        , "Eat glass"
        , "Suicide by cop"
    };
    RNG rng;
    int kill_count{};
    std::cout 
        << "Welcome to the Suicide Game!\n\n"
        << "How do you want to kill yourself this time?\n";
    do {
        std::cout
            << '\n'
            << methods[rng.random_method(std::size(methods))]
            << "\nCurrent death total is: " 
            << ++kill_count
            << "\n\n";
    } while (get_yes_no("Kill yourself again? (y/n): "));
    std::cout << "\n\nFinal death total is: " << kill_count << "\n\n";
}
```

Here is function main:

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>

// Class `RNG` ...

// Function `to_upper` ...

// Function `trim_whitespace` ...

// Function `get_yes_no` ...

// Function `kill_game` ...

int main() {
    kill_game();
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

###### Sample run (with input errors)

Output from a sample run:

```
Welcome to the Suicide Game!

How do you want to kill yourself this time?

Drunk driving
Current death total is: 1

Kill yourself again? (y/n):
Invalid entry. Please reenter.

Kill yourself again? (y/n): garbage keystrokes
Invalid entry. Please reenter.

Kill yourself again? (y/n): y

Starving or dehydrating
Current death total is: 2

Kill yourself again? (y/n): y

Fall damage
Current death total is: 3

Kill yourself again? (y/n): n


Final death total is: 3
```

Comment: `using namespace std;` is bad. Something like `using std::cout;` especially tightly is not bad.

Comment: Yup! Something like `using std::cout;` is usually not a good idea at the file level. Inside a function or class, or within a block, is a different story. And when you want ADL to kick in, for overloaded functions like `swap`, it becomes essential.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for so much detail and examples! I was using w3schools to learn and they said to always use namespace std; so I did without researching beforehand. Alot of your suggestions make it much simpler and easier, and I'll look into how I can learn how to use them :)